# HTML file and CSS file for buttons that are links?

Tags: html, css

I know his has been discussed but I can't seem to get a clear answer.

I would like to create two buttons, once they are clicked they act like links to different pages. I used this code below in my HTML file and created a css file to edit the appearance of the buttons. My question is how do I name the two buttons in the html file so that for example I can edit their styles in the CSS file individually.

[HTML Code]

```
      <button onclick="location.href='something.html'">Click this</button>

      <button onclick="location.href='http://www.blah.com'">Click this too</button
```

[CSS code]

```
             button{
             float: left;
             position: relative;
             left: 40%;
             background: red;

             }
```

Comment: If you have a link, use a link, and then style the link to look like a button. As far as how to style them individually, it sounds like you need to learn HTML & CSS in general, which is not what Stack Overflow is for. Consider googling a tutorial or buying a book. [MDN is a good place to start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).

Comment: Yes I was going to do that but thought it was easier the way I did it and I actually found that exact code on here because someone had a similar question then realized I cannot edit the buttons individually that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People will tell you to style links like buttons, which is, while elegant, not supported. I often did this a long time ago for navigation links, and I only ended up finding the `padding-bottom` and `padding-top` being ruled out by the user agent. This is because links, or `<a>` are `inline` elements, and inline elements dont respond the same way as `block`s do.

Encompassing the `button` in a `a` was my solution, along with pointing my CSS at thte buttons. The `a` tag can be ignored, except for when adding your link.

```
<a href="http://example.com">
    <button>Example</button>
</a>
```

Comment: My question is how to style them individually. My solution is doing just that. I can change the color of each button and the size... If you have a way to do that share because what you put up there is very generic.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle. I style buttons in size, transitions, colors, borders, anything. Sky is the limit. https://jsfiddle.net/joshcrowe/yfy10wmm/

Answer (score 3):

You would use a class or ID to distinguish the two elements

```css
#button1 {
  background: red
}
#button2 {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Click this</button>
<button id="button2">Click this too</button
```

The barebone basics of CSS.

Comment: Actually I just tried it and I don't think that is what I needed since the button   are links. I think I will have to format the links to look like buttons or leave them the way I did. But  thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I didn't give you the exact HTML to use, obviously. What I gave you was instruction on how to use ID attributes and assign styles to them.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question but thanks for your help. anyways.